# Auto refresh JavaScript function stop working after some time

Tags: php, javascript, canvas

i need to refresh image in every 5 sec. without flicker. so search google and find some solution.
but that Code refresh image and without flicker but it stop refresh image after some time.
some time its stop refresh image after 1 min, some time after 3 min some time after 15 min.

Here is my code

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>

<script language="JavaScript">
var x = 0,
    y = 0;
var canvas, context, img;

function timedRefresh() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("x");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    img = new Image();
    img.src = "CC4.png?" + Math.random();
    img.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(img, x, y);
        x += 0;
        y += 0;
        setTimeout('timedRefresh()', 5000);
    };
}
window.onload = timedRefresh;

</script>
</head>

<body id="home" onload="setTimeout('timedRefresh()',5000)">
<canvas id="x" width="800" height="590"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `img.src = "CC4.png?" +  Math.random();`

Is everything right in this line of code ?

Comment: @harsha That just stops caching normally, unless it plays a specific role in this code.

Comment: @harsha You do this to dirtily prevent browserside caching.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is a network issue so it stops when it can't load the image. Try adding

```
img.onerror = function(){ setTimeout('timedRefresh()', 1000); }
```

so it retries the load even if there was an issue

Comment: anywhere after img is defined (eg. before the img.onload)